Leaving non-English dialogue untranslated?
I am now on the third draft of my first novel, which is written in English and based in Slovakia.
99% of the novel is in English, though occasionally there is some Slovak dialogue which I have not translated by choice.
Some of my beta readers have said it should be translated. I prefer not to because:

there is no system for this - footnotes, endnotes or parentheses - which I like
it adds a layer of immersion and authenticity

However, I am completely aware that though I may know what the text means, it may be frustrating for a reader not to know.
Should I leave it untranslated as I wish, or translate it [if I had to, I'd use parentheses].
What is the best thing to do from the point of view of the story? Is it common in novels for foreign text to be left untranslated?

For the 99% in English - is this understood to be characters speaking Slovakian (but translated for the reader - i.e. using "translation convention") or are they actually speaking English "in-universe"?

... also is what's being said important for the reader?

In previous centuries it was commonplace to include quotes and phrases from different languages, with some writers being more notorious for it than others. Edgar Allen Poe and Arthur Conan Doyle spring to mind, both including untranslated French philosophy quotes in their writing. It would be expected of the reader to be educated enough to either know the quote, or be able to translate it.
Writers since have hard-pivoted from that point of view in recent years, realising it's not that useful to ostracise part of your reader base for nothing more than a thinly veiled intellectual flex. Providing translations in footnotes or glossaries has been popular for a spell, but depending on the frequency this just becomes tedious for the reader to follow.
The approach many comics take nowadays is either putting the translated text in English (or the language of the book) and using different fonts or [{< brackets >}] to indicate these things are said in a different language. Alternatively, if they aren't meant to be understood by the reader or the character hearing this, left untranslated. This works for comics, as the scene description is within the picture and the fact that there is spoken language must be acknowledged with speech bubbles.
However, in written text, this approach doesn't work, as the speech itself isn't a requirement for the description of the scene. Simple descriptions as "they spoke a few words in an unknown language" would suffice. Simply putting text in foreign languages and leaving it untranslated might help for immersion, but it's quite possible most readers won't find it as endearing as intended. Readers are curious by nature, after all, and would either be annoyed there is information included they aren't privy to, or spend the time translating it by whatever means, breaking immersion completely.
Now that is not to say that it's always wrong to leave text untranslated, but there are only a few niche cases where this would be acceptable. For example, if the character remembers the untranslated text and finds the meaning of it afterwards, leaving it untranslated would help to further the plot and deepen the mystery.
In conclusion, if the information conveyed isn't pivotal enough to the narrative to warrant a translation for the reader (all readers), it can be cut altogether. If it is, a translation should be provided promptly to avoid breaking immersion or ostracizing your readers.
Lastly, additional to the excellent approaches suggested by the other answer, you could also use the approach of the answer/reaction that includes the question:
Character 1: "Als het zulk lekker weer is, krijg ik altijd zin in aardbeienijs."
Character 2: "Why yes, it is quite a nice day for an ice cream. Although, I prefer vanilla over strawberry."

The convention today is to write the whole of the novel in the language of the target audience. Foreign dialogue is commonly translated and the original language mentioned in the text (e.g. "She said in Spanish: 'English translation of what she said in Spanish.' "). Do not provide translations in footnotes or parentheses! Translate the passage in text! Single words and short expressions ("¡Hola!") may be left in the foreign language if they are either well known or their meaning can be easily (!) inferred from the context.
If for some reason you absolutely must have longer sentence in a foreign language, you can paraphrase them in the surrounding text, e.g.:

He explained to me that I had to turn left at the next intersection: "An der nächsten Abzweigung biegen Sie nach links ab."

But this is unneccessary. The foreign passage adds nothing to those who cannot read it and just repeats what the paraphrase already says for those who can. Instead, you can just give the paraphrase and skip the foreign passage altogther:

He explained to me in German that I had to turn left at the next intersection. I thanked him and walked on.

Write in two or more languages only if you are certain that your target audience knows all the languages. Otherwise, don't.
Remember: If you aim to publish your work, you are not writing for yourself, but for your readers. A foreign passage adds immersion and authenticity only if your readers understand it. Otherwise it is just irritating and lazy.

I’ll use Spanish for this because it’s the only other language I can confidently write, but this goes for any language, no matter how widely spoken they are. You could even do this with a conlang!

“Buenas días,” she greeted.

In this example, it’s clear that this is a greeting, even if it’s not as common as hola (I’m exaggerating, honestly it’s pretty common).

“Eres muy linda,” he complimented her.

Again, it’s clear this is a compliment! Through other contextual clues, you could add weight to this, e.g.

“Qué linda eres,” he complimented her. She blushed, hiding her face in
her hands.  “I’m not that pretty,” she said shyly.

Or something like that. I’m not an expert. Anyways, this makes it clear that he’s talking about her being pretty. You can use this in other ways, too-- it doesn't always have to be from a character's outward reaction, although I think the POV character should probably speak the language?

"Querido," they called him. He recognized the term of endearment.

Alternatively-

"Querido," they called him. Dear.

The second one is more of the character's inner monologue translating, whereas the first one could apply to a character who is fluent in the language or a character who recognizes the term for some reason (has lived around that language for a while, has dated someone who spoke that language, et cetera).
Basically, dialogue tags can be used for almost everything. If they don't fit, you just need to use a tiny bit of context or the POV character's monologue. Here are some dialogue tags that I would use:
pleaded, cursed, spat, swore, dismissed, giggled, scolded, etc.
My personal rule of thumb is to use dialogue tags with emotional connotations, and not words that could be synonyms for said. If they convey emotion, perfect! If they convey tone, great as long as it's clear! Something like "whispered" or "stated" doesn't help translating in my opinion.

@C26 this is the person you replied to, I didn’t have enough reputation to comment and then someone edited my post. i was in the middle of deleting my account when you replied so it made me a new one I think

"i was in the middle of deleting my account when you replied so it made me a new one I think" - that's exactly what happened, yes. I edited your post because answers should be standalone rather than responding to other answers or comments. C26 won't be pinged by the comment you just left, as they haven't commented on this answer, though they will have been pinged when you first posted the answer. I'm not sure what the best solution is in terms of merging your answers together - perhaps edit the information from your first answer into this one?
